# my react simple project has a compiled error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, node-modules

Module not found: Error: Package path ./client is not exported from package E:\React\react redux project\myapp\node_modules\react (see exports field in E:\React\react redux project\myapp\node_modules\react\package.json)

a simple react project for begin :
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.render(

## Hello World!

,document.getElementById("root"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `react-dom/client` like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
//..
const rootElement = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
rootElement.render(
 <App />
)
```

or another way

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
//..
const rootElement = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
rootElement.render(
 <App />
)
```